# html5 new layout elements old browsers

Tags: layout, html, cross-browser

I have **my site** ( http://www.rohanjain.in) based on **html5**. It uses the new elements defined in html5 for page layout: *header*, *nav*, *section*, *article*, *footer* etc. But I just checked that with old browsers and ie (dont care about this "non" browser) dont render the page properly.

**Snapshot**: 
[image]

The css markup (source of css at http://www.rohanjain.in/media/css/style.src.css) is not being followed maybe because it does not recognize the tags.

Currently for old browsers visitors are redirected to [this](http://www.rohanjain.in/old-browser/) and for ie [this](http://www.rohanjain.in/ie/) page.

Could not find a proper solution to this. Is there any workaround so that the page can be rendered properly and with html5?

Comment: This might help (for Firefox 2): http://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-firefox-2

Comment: Haha... "get a web-browser" for IE visitors. :) Have you checked out IE9? It's not bad actually.

Comment: hmm heard it is better. Dont use windows much...but this message will stay at least for users below ie9 on my site.

Comment: Your are right about the CSS part: it's only applied to tags that the browser support because in HTML you can't define your own tags, so any CSS for unknown tags is discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [HTML5Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)?

Answer (score 3):

Use the HTML 5 remy sharp script to `document.createElement` them:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

http://work.arounds.org/issue/19/styling-html-5-elements-ie/

Also you have to declare `display:block` for all the HTML5 block level elements manually:

```
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
    display:block
}
```

Comment: yeah...already did that, you may see my css source provided in the question. What I want to get done is to get it look right in other older browsers like ff2 not in ie.

Comment: Apply the same **internal** code to FF2 if you care about it. Personally, I wouldn't worry about FF2.