# What are the best practices to make a HTML5 page look same in browsers?

Tags: html, cross-browser, backwards-compatibility

HTML5 comes with many new features such as new tags and many of these features are supported by the latest generation of browsers.

What are the best practices to make a HTML5 page look same in all versions of the popular browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari)?

Comment: for my own reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175050/html5-new-layout-elements-old-browsers

Answer (score 1):

[The best practice](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) is [to not attempt](http://www.noupe.com/design/websites-shouldnt-look-the-same-across-different-browsers%E2%80%A6here-is-why.html) to [make it look the same in all browsers](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/).  Web design [does not work like print design](http://www.zeldman.com/2010/07/05/an-indesign-for-html-and-css/), you don't have control over the ultimate output, the user does.  This is a strength of the web, not a limitation.

Comment: how people use modernizer to make their site compatible for all old browser version. can u give bit hint. what HTML5Shiv does? how it is different from modernizer in terms of functionality. looking for discussion. thanks

Comment: @Thomas 1. If you want to know about modernizr and HTML5Shiv you should ask questions about them; 2. If you're looking for discussion, this is the wrong website for you.

Comment: if u know something about modernizr and HTML5Shiv then u can briefly discuss about here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Test. Have a copy of each and test again. If it works in IE, but not a modern browser, then your markup is wrong. So choose the browser you think is consistently correct and test there first. Chances are good that if it works in a modern browser then it will work anywhere except IE which will almost always be the exception.

Comment: how people use modernizer to make their site compatible for all old browser version. can u give bit hint. what HTML5Shiv does? how it is different from modernizer in terms of functionality. looking for discussion. thanks